# Squid best practices for caching

Tags: reverse-proxy, squid

I have setup squid in for caching and have used pointers from [Last.fm post](http://blog.last.fm/2007/08/30/squid-optimization-guide).

Though I have high capacity servers, since Squid is able to use only processor core, the CPU usage seems to be really high. Is there a better way to optimize squid to use less CPU?

I have tried using tcmalloc, and disabling ESI but none of this help.